Issue with Go Application on Kubernetes: Informer Blocked on Semaphore
We are encountering an issue in our Go application running as a Kubernetes pod that uses multiple informers. Analysis of the dump file revealed that a goroutine is primarily blocked on acquiring a semaphore, likely due to resource contention or I/O delays. This is related to the Kubernetes logging mechanism and the Informer's Reflector watch process, suggesting potential problems with logging and reflecting changes from the API server.
Below is the informer code block
func CreateInformer(label string, podname PodName) {
    kube, err := kube.NewKubeClient()

    if err != nil {
        log.Error().Err(err).Msg("Error while getting kube client")
        return
    }
    informerOption1 := informers.WithTweakListOptions(func(opts *metav1.ListOptions) {
        opts.FieldSelector = "status.phase=Running"
        opts.LabelSelector = fmt.Sprintf("app=%s", label)
    })
    informerFactory1 := informers.NewSharedInformerFactoryWithOptions(kube, 0, informerOption1)
    podInformer1 := informerFactory1.Core().V1().Pods()
    podInformer1.Informer().AddEventHandler(kubecache.ResourceEventHandlerFuncs{

        AddFunc: func(new interface{}) {
            if pod, ok := new.(*corev1.Pod); ok {
                log.Debug().Msg("Pod " + pod.Name + " Created")
                UpdateCacheDetails(podInformer1, podname)
            }
        },
        UpdateFunc: func(old, new interface{}) {
            if pod, ok := new.(*corev1.Pod); ok {
                log.Debug().Msg("Pod " + pod.Name + " updated")
                UpdateCacheDetails(podInformer1, podname)
            }
        },
        DeleteFunc: func(old interface{}) {
            if pod, ok := old.(*corev1.Pod); ok {
                log.Debug().Msg("Pod " + pod.Name + " deleted")
                UpdateCacheDetails(podInformer1, podname)
            }
        },
    })
    go func() {
        informerFactory1.Start(wait.NeverStop)
    }()
    go func() {
        informerFactory1.WaitForCacheSync(wait.NeverStop)
    }()

} 

Below is the informer method for CRDs
  
func CreateCRDInformer() {
    _, kubeconfig, err := kube.NewKubeClientWithConfig()
    if err != nil {
        log.Error().Err(err).Msg("Error while getting kube client")
        return
    }
    dynamicClient, err := dynamic.NewForConfig(kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error().Err(err).Msg("Error while getting dynamic client")
        return
    }
    resource := schema.GroupVersionResource{Group: "stable.com", Version: "v1", Resource: "workloads"}
    factory := dynamicinformer.NewFilteredDynamicSharedInformerFactory(dynamicClient,
        time.Second, "", nil)
    informer := factory.ForResource(resource).Informer()
    crdEventHandler := func(obj interface{}) {
        lister := dynamiclister.New(informer.GetIndexer(), resource)
        workloads, err := lister.List(labels.Everything())
        if err != nil {
            log.Error().Err(err).Msg("Error while getting workload data")
            return
        }
        log.Info().Msg("UpdateWorkloadCache : Create/Delete")
        UpdateWorkloadCache(workloads)
    }
    informer.AddEventHandler(kubecache.ResourceEventHandlerFuncs{
        AddFunc: crdEventHandler,
        UpdateFunc: func(oldObj, newObj interface{}) {
            oldObjJson, err := json.Marshal(oldObj)
            if err != nil {
                log.Err(err).Msg("oldObjJson marshall failed")
            }
            newObjJson, err := json.Marshal(newObj)
            if err != nil {
                log.Err(err).Msg("oldObjJson marshall failed")
            }

            opts := jsondiff.DefaultConsoleOptions()
            opts.PrintTypes = false
            result, _ := jsondiff.Compare(newObjJson, oldObjJson, &opts)
            if result != jsondiff.FullMatch {
                log.Info().Msg("UpdateWorkloadCache : Update")
                lister := dynamiclister.New(informer.GetIndexer(), resource)
                workloads, err := lister.List(labels.Everything())
                if err != nil {
                    log.Error().Err(err).Msg("Error while getting workload data")
                    return
                }
                UpdateWorkloadCache(workloads)
            }
        },
        DeleteFunc: crdEventHandler,
    })
    go informer.Run(wait.NeverStop)

    // Wait for the informer cache to be synced
    if !kubecache.WaitForCacheSync(wait.NeverStop, informer.HasSynced) {
        log.Error().Err(err).Msg("Error syncing informer cache")
        return
    }
}

We observed the following log entry from the custom resource informer:
Error :
E0627 09:19:08.998638 1 reflector.go:140] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.26.1/tools/cache/reflector.go:169: Failed to watch *unstructured.Unstructured: unknown.

There is no semaphore in your code, and the “dump file” or analysis you've done is also missing, Please post a reproducible example.

I am not using semaphore in my code. But during execution, may be  semaphore is called from included libraries, which I got to know from stack trace from Delve (a debugger for Go programs) is as below:
**
 "Goroutine 116 - User: .usr/local/go/src/os/file_posix.go:46 os.(*File).Write (0x4ea291) [semacquire 25180927464292648]",
**
Getting this from delve analysis  This  shows problem with synchronization semaphore or mutex (semacquire).
